# Updating an RDD based on value of the other RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, functional-programming, apache-spark-mllib

I want to update an rdd based on the values of another rdd. I've tried these three approaches:
1. use left join
2. use subtract by Key and then union
3. use a map and if conditions inside it

However the three approaches mentioned are so slow.

Here's an example:
rdd1 contains an rdd based on distinct userID and productID I have. Example, if I have user Id from 0 to 100, I have product Ids from 0 to 100. I have to initially have a rating of 0s for all of them.
rdd1 = [(1,1,0.0),(1,2,0.0),(1,3,0.0),...,(100,100,0.0)]

Then rdd2 contains the ratings of specific userIds and productIds. 
rdd2 = [(1,1,3.0),(100,100,4.0)]

What I want is to include all userIds and productIds in the matrix for collaborative filtering even though there is no rating corresponding to it. I need to do this in order to use explicit ALS in Spark MLLib. If I'm not going to augment 0, I will be getting nonsensical results as the code for explicit does not include scenario wherein there are unobserved values. Thus, they are considered missing instead of zero.

In short, I want to produce this rdd:
rdd =  [(1,1,3.0),(1,1,0.0),(1,2,0.0),...,(100,100,4.0)]

Do you have some ideas on the fastest way to do this in terms of running time? I have two rdd with millions of entries to be used in updating.

Comment: Please share the actual code you wrote. How do you choose which value should be set for each key?

Comment: Can you provide a better example? You example is ambiguous.

Comment: The first rdd I have have all values of 0. What I am doing is to append the entries of 0 to the second rdd. I have to update the values of rdd1 based on the values of rdd2. If the key in rdd1 is found in rdd2, I have to use that value instead of 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
val res: RDD[(Integer, Integer)] = 
  rdd1.leftOuterJoin(rdd2)
      .mapValues { case (v, wOpt) => wOpt.getOrElse(v) }
```

Comment: leftOuterJoin takes really slow for spark 1.5.1 which is prior to the change in spark 1.6 that uses sortMerge instead of leftJoin(which uses crossJoin and filtering). If I'm not going to use leftOuterJoin, is there another faster way I can do this. I'm using millions of entries in my rdds.